# How to use std::min_element in C++17?

Tags: c++, min, c++17

I have small piece of code to print smallest element in the range using [std::min_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element). cppreference example print the index of smallest element, but i want to print smallest element instead of index number.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{3, 1, 4, 1, -5, 9};
    std::cout << std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
}
```

But, I got following an error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:8:15: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >')
     std::cout << std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
```

So, What's the wrong with my code?

Comment: Just like you'd use it in C++14.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at the `std::min_element` declaration:

```
template <class ForwardIterator>
  ForwardIterator min_element ( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last );
```

you see that it returns an iterator. So you have to dereference it to access the actual value:

```
std::cout << *std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
```

The rationale of that is obvious: what if you want to do anything other than printing the value, such as deleting it?