# Why do I get a different result if instead of x I directly pass array element ar[0] in std::remove function?

Tags: c++, vector, erase-remove-idiom

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> ar = {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7};
    vector<int> sum;
    int n = ar.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int x = ar[0];
        int frq = count(ar.begin(), ar.end(), x);
        int q = frq / 2;
        sum.push_back(q);

        ar.erase(remove(ar.begin(), ar.end(), x), ar.end()); // Doubt
    }
    int count = 0;
    int n1 = sum.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        count = count + sum[i];
    }
    cout << count;
}
```

Why do I get a different result if instead of `x` I directly pass `ar[0]` in the `std::remove` function?

`x` and `ar[0]` have the same value.

Comment: Are you asking why you get a different result if you use `ar.erase(remove(ar.begin(),ar.end(),ar[0]),ar.end());` instead of `ar.erase(remove(ar.begin(),ar.end(),x),ar.end());`?

Comment: what results do you get?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `std::remove` takes the last parameter by reference. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove):

> Because std::remove takes value by reference, it can have unexpected behavior if it is a reference to an element of the range [first, last).

It is a bit tricky, because the paramter is passed as `const` reference:

> ```
> template< class ForwardIt, class T >
> ForwardIt remove( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value );
> ```

However, just because `ar[0]` is passed as `const` reference does not imply that `ar[0]` cannot be modified by other means. In this case it is modified through `first` / `last`. Actually I cannot think of a case where it would be "ok" to have an element inside `[first, last)` as `value`.

For illustration, consider that you get the same wrong output with `ar[0]` as if you declared `x` as a reference:

```
int& x=ar[0];
ar.erase(remove(ar.begin(),ar.end(),x),ar.end());
```

Here `x` is passed as `const` reference, but the algorithm does modify `ar[0]`.

Comment: I wonder what "unexpected" means. Is it "undefined" or "unspecified"? Can't find it in the [reference](https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.remove).

Comment: @cigien I was wondering the same, didnt check the standard. I find the text on cppref a bit misleading "Removes all elements that are equal to value, using operator== to compare them." that sounds as if order of those comparisons wouldnt matter at all, but it does.  On the other hand I wouldnt be too surprised if the standard does not specifically mentions this case

Comment: @cigien, [in this duplicate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59348038/6865932) there is a discussion about the same matter.

Comment: @anastaciu interesting, but make sure to read till the end, turns out that eventually it was agreed that there is no UB

Comment: @idclev463035818, yes.

Comment: @idclev463035818 but "there doesn't appear to be any UB here" is definitely not a smoking gun.